# Autodesk Inventor: Ghost surface appearing while extruding a profile that was imported from dxf file

Tags: autodesk-inventor

I have used 'trace bitmap' feature of Inkscape on an image and saved it as DXF file. I have opened this DXF file in Autodesk Inventor using 'DWG/DXF File Wizard' (selected options attached as screenshot).

[image]

Now when I try to Extrude some of the closed profiles on this sketch, I can see some ghost surfaces appearing over there on mouse move.

[image]

When I click the intersecting area (of ghost and profile), the desired profile does not gets selected but something else and I can't undo it using Ctrl+Click.

[image]

Below is the screen shot of the closed profile that does not overlap with ghost surface and gets highlighted properly and even when I select it, correct Extrude operation takes place.

[image]

Here is my [DXF File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_T3mrLuZti6TBG4K52HejFQgVdsW3qZw/view?usp=sharing). Please don't ask me what kind of design it contains :). The screenshot below shows the area where ghost surface appears while extruding it.

[image]

I am guessing that my DXF file contains some Z axis value and that is causing the problem. Can someone guide me in the right direction.

Note: I don't have AutoCAD installed on my machine.

System Config:
Windows 10; 
Autodesk Inventor Professional 2018

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a graphics issue only. I test your DXF in Autocad 2020 and I try to import it to Inventor 2020 and everything looks OK.
But the sketch is too complex for work. I'm not able to create final body from whole DXF.
When it is possible use texture instead of real model.
When you need to manufacture this, use your dxf directly.